# Value Undefined: Loops in async await with Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am working on a project where I need to brute force `PDF` password.

For that `PDF.js` is used for verifying password and `promise.race` to run parallel functions to make the overall work fast.

and this is how i implemented it:

```
var sfile = "KRIS.pdf"
var dBuf = fs.readFileSync(sfile);
const tryCases = getCombos(alphaArray, 4); // permutation having total length 456976
var finishFunction = false;
async function getPass(startAt = Number(), endAt = Number()) {
  var isDone = false;
  var currentPass = ''
  for (let index = startAt; index < endAt; index++) {
    if (finishFunctions) { return; }
    currentPass = tryCases[index].join("");

    await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: dBuf, password: currentPass }).promise
      .then((r) => {
        console.log('Worked: ' + currentPass);
        isDone = true;
        pdfjsLib.distroy();
        return new Promise.resolve();
      })
      .catch((e) => {  })

    if (isDone) {
      finishFunctions = true;
      return currentPass;
    }
  }
console.log(`Hey Nothing From ${startAt} - ${endAt}`);
}

console.time('Found ');
Promise.race([
  getPass(0, 100000),
  getPass(100000, 200000),
  getPass(200000, 300000),
  getPass(300000, 400000),
  getPass(400000, 456976)
])
  .then((s) => { console.timeEnd('Found '); console.log('HeyThen ' + s) })
  .catch((e) => console.log('Hey Error ' + e));
```

now it works to get the 4 letter password but There are problems preventing it from being complete.

**First** Current Function is very very slow, it takes forever even after running parallel functions.

**Second** I added a flag to stop other parallel functions but it does not work as expected with 4 Letter Forcing.

**Third** Resource usage is really high. My Linux system stops responding.

for visualizing the time and flag issue I used 3 letters forcing and here is log of it:

```
Worked: KRIS
Found: 13950.743ms
HeyThen KRIS
Hey Nothing From 4934 - 8788
Hey Nothing From 0 - 4394
Hey Nothing From 13182 - 17576
(node:3068) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

Comment: Your original code (with the one single loop) does not use `await` and would fire all `myFunc.getDocument(…)` calls at the same time. Your `ATryCase` function does the calls sequentially (`await`ing them one after the other), so if anything it should be slower. If both of them take the same time, that would suggest your `getDocument` function does internal queuing anyway and there's hardly room for improvement.

Comment: Given your `ATryCase` function accesses multiple documents (not just a single one), what value do you expect it to return?

Comment: 1. i never said that my single loop uses await. I said why normal loop takes same time as the promise based one which are divided into multiple jobs.  2. `myFunc.getDocument` is promise based function and if i don't use the await on that then the functions is messed up. getDocument isn't doing much. it just verifies if the `currentPos` is the correct value to process. Think it as a password checking program. Every time it is verifying the `currentPos` if it's true break the loop and return the currentPos.

Comment: What do you mean by "*divided into multiple jobs*"? Every `myFunc.getDocument(…)` is already its own job. The only difference is between calling them all at once or one after the other.

Comment: not good at using exact words. by that i meant `using of Promise.race` . 4 `ATryCase` is called each with having 30 iteration the one who finds it first returns it.

Comment: Wait, you want the iterations to stop when `getDocument` has "found" something?

Comment: yeesss that's the point. if the currentPass is correct then `myFunc.getDocument.then(()` will be fired and this the point where i need to break the loop and return the value `currentPos` back.

Comment: "*getDocument isn't doing much. it just verifies if the currentPos is the correct value to process. Think it as a password checking program.*" - can you post its code? I have a hunch that it is not actually doing anything asynchronous.

Comment: Whole code posted please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `return new Promise.resolve(currentPass);` you return a result to `then` and not from `ATryCase`. Write the result of `await myFunc.getDocument` to some variable and return it

```
const res = await myFunc.getDocument({ data: dBuf, pos: currentPass })
      .promise
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Data is: ' + currentPass);
        console.timeEnd('GotData ');
        return new Promise.resolve(currentPass);
      }).catch(e => { });
return res;
```

Comment: i didn't get it. what's the point ? using it inside the loop would make it exit in the first iteration. I need to return current pass only if the the myFunc is true or resolved.

Comment: There is no code about checking against `true` in your original code. If `myFunc.getDocument` successfullay resolved then `return res` is executed. If `myFunc.getDocument` is rejected then you'll be thrown out of `ATryCase` and you can catch this case outside in the `catch` block. Do you want to return first successful execution of `myFunc.getDocument` regardless of previous rejected attempts?

Comment: when `myFunc` resolves i need to stop there and return the value of `currentPass` . and i tried that in  the function but it did not worked. i am never rejecting the myFunc, why ? because i am using the `race` where first resolved promise is returned and i just want to resolve one which finds the value correct. I hope i explained it good.

Answer (score 0):

> if the `currentPass` is correct, i need to break the loop and return the value

None of your code snippets did that so far. You will want to use something like

```
async function ATryCase(indexStart, indexEnd) {
  for (let index = indexStart; index < indexEnd; index++) {
    var currentPass = startLetters + index;
    try {
      await myFunc.getDocument({ data: dBuf, pos: currentPass }).promise;
      console.log('Data is: ' + currentPass);
      return currentPass; // this breaks the loop and `return`s from ATryCase
    } catch {
      continue;
    }
  }
  throw new Error("No pass did find a result");
}
```

for that.

Alternatively, have a look at the proposed [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any), which would do exactly what you are looking for, but concurrently. (You will also want to use it in place of `Promise.race` if you go for 4 concurrent sequential searches). You could use it like

```
function ATryCase(indexStart, indexEnd) {
  const promises = [];
  for (let index = indexStart; index < indexEnd; index++) {
    var currentPass = startLetters + index;
    promises.push(myFunc.getDocument({ data: dBuf, pos: currentPass }).promise.then(() => {
      console.log('Data is: ' + currentPass);
      return currentPass;
    }));
  }
  return Promise.any(promises);
}
```

Comment: `None of your code snippets did that so far` I did it with the promise based function just wanted to know what's wrong with the async one. However this was the secondary question, The main was why there is no performance increment when using `promise.race` ? The single loop is iterating 89 times and finishes in 450ms while `promise.race`  which is calling the function multiple times, is too finishing it in 450ms why is that.

Comment: @ChandraShekharAazad If by "promise-based function" you mean the first snippet, no, that did not stop the iteration when something was found, and it did not `return` anything from the function at all. It only logs the results it finds.

Comment: @ChandraShekharAazad And why there is no improvement using `Promise.race` I already explained in the comments on the question. The original code did nothing sequentially but all in parallel (starting all calls at once) as well. Using `await` would at best mean a slowdown.

Comment: hey @Bergi can you please take a look ? at updated question